# Why search in .Net Dictionary is slower than in .Net List

Tags: c#, time-complexity

I tried to solve this task:
We have an array, eg. [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 7, 8, 1], find and output duplicates. For this array the result is
1, 2.

I wrote code to try "slow" and "fast" solutions.
"Slow" solution with inner loop and searching via list

```
   public uint[] InnerLoops(uint[] arr)
    {
        var timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        var result = new List<uint>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j] && result.All(a => a != arr[j]))
                    result.Add(arr[j]);
            }
        }

        timer.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Seconds: {timer.Elapsed}");

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

I would estimate the solutions as O(n^2) and O(n) inside each inner loop. Sorry, I am not good at estimating complexity. Anyway, I thought, the following solution would be better

```
 public uint[] OneLoopDictionary(uint[] arr)
    {
        var timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<uint, bool>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            // Key - number, value - true if duplicates
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(arr[i]))
            {
                dictionary[arr[i]] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary[arr[i]] = false;
            }
        }

        var result = new List<uint>();
        foreach (var item in dictionary)
        {
            if (item.Value)
                result.Add(item.Key);
        }

        timer.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Seconds: {timer.Elapsed}");

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

The complexity is O(2n) - one loop and loop via dictionary.

I was surprised that the fist solution with loop was faster that the second one. Could anyone explain me why?

Comment: Accessing a dictionary/hashtable also has an overhead, which becomes especially noticable for small values of `n`

Comment: Also Stopwatch is not a benchmarking tool

Comment: @TheGeneral Do you think we could get that on t-shirts?

Comment: @John `shirt.SetText("Stopwatch is not a benchmarking tool")`

Comment: Please try with a large array, witnessing O() (asymptotic) complexity with only n ~= 10 is not easy. Try n = 100 then n  = 1000.

Comment: @John Not sure if link is shareable... https://www.customink.com/ndx/?cid=dvx0-00cb-t14t . And there is a lot of room for improvement, as it was random choices all along.

Comment: @John https://i.ibb.co/5vzFJzj/Capture.png available in other cuts https://i.ibb.co/qxvqPJz/Capture2.png

Comment: @TheGeneral I'd like to order 2. Also available as Girlies?

Comment: @Fildor sure thing!

Comment: Only compare the read times. Not the time to create the dictionary.  The adding items to a dictionary is always longer than adding items to a list.  The dictionary only saves time when reading lots of items because there is an overhead in creating the dictionary.

Comment: @TheGeneral ok, let's switch this on a meta post?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all! Espesially to who gave an advice to try with bigger array. I tryied with 100, 1000 and 100000 and I was surprised, that the dictionary was faster. Of course, previously, I tryied not just with array from my first post, bur with array of about 50 numbers, but the dictionary was slower.

With aaray of 100 or more numbers the dictuinary is much more faster. The result for 100000 items is:
list - 31 seconds,
dicionary - 0.008 seconds